# Vue image from base64 or ArrayBuffer

Tags: vue.js, flask, websocket, base64, vuex

I have a flask backend, which sends an image to the vue frontend [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399948/flask-socketio-send-images):

```
with open('my_image_file.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    image_data = f.read()
emit('IMAGE', {'image_data': image_data})
```

On the vue frontend, the image should ultimately be shown on the webpage. I guess the easiest way would be to somehow save the image in the static Folder. I would have an action like this in my store:

```
const actions = {
  SOCKET_IMAGE (commit, image) {
    console.log("image received")

    /* What needs to be done to save image in 'static/' ?*/

    commit.commit('image_saved')
  }
}
```

I am also open for alternative ways to save the image and render it on the webpage. Can I save the image directly in the vuex store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the image data in Vuex

Store:

```js
const state = {
  imgData: null
}
```

Assuming you're getting `base64` from the API, commit the raw data:

```js
commit('SET_IMAGE_DATA', image);
```

Or, if you're getting an `ArrayBuffer`, convert it first:

```js
function _arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    return window.btoa( binary );
}

const imgData = _arrayBufferToBase64(image)
commit('SET_IMAGE_DATA', imgData);
```

<sup>*ArrayBuffer to base64 method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string)*</sup>

And use it in your template :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="'data:image/png;base64,' + $store.state.imgData" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: ```<img data-v-ef5cfeca="" src="data:image/png;base64,[object ArrayBuffer]">``` appears in the html, but image could not be loaded (broken image symbol) any ideas?

Comment: Seems you're getting an ArrayBuffer. Try my updated answer

Comment: @Dan `$store.state.imgData` -> why not teach to create a getter instead?

Comment: @balexandre It's not a great use case for a getter; a custom component would be more appropriate. Plus I don't wish to confuse with tangential topics, especially since this one is already tackling image conversion